# JS Keyboard Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events

i want to scroll down and up between div`s with id scroll0 to scroll2:

At index.html, I have something like that:

```
<div id="scroll0"></div>
<div id="scroll1"></div>
<div id="scroll2"></div>
```

Script is:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: aid.offset().top
}, 'slow');
}

var count = 1;

$(document).keydown(function (event) {
var counter = count++;
var destinationDown = "#scroll" + counter;
var destinationTop = destinationDown //counter--;

if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    //Scroll down
    scrollToAnchor($(destinationDown));
} else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    //Scroll up
    scrollToAnchor($(destinationTop));
}
});
```

Scrolling down is fine, but how to scroll up from different div`s to top.

For example how to scroll from div with id scroll0 to scroll1 and from scroll1 to scroll0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle going up you need to not always increment counter straight away.

```
var counter = count++;
```

This will have to be done after working out the key that was pressed, and if the keycode is 38, then you will have to subtract from count rather than increase.

You will also have to handle wrap arounds, because you only have 3 divs to scroll to, if you are at the bottom and you press down, your code will currently break.

My suggestion would be to firstly change your counter to be an index and in your keydown handler to do the following:

1. Check if up/down was pressed
2. Calculate the correct next index to scroll to (if you are on 0 and you press up you go to 2. If you are on 2 and you press down, you go to 0. If you are on 0 and you press down, you go to 1, etc)
3. Update your index variable
4. Scroll to the new index